# DateFormat with Country Locales issue

Tags: java, localization, date-format

I'm writing a multilingual Program and I have set my Locales to Country specific ones (e.g. de_AT, de_DE,en_US,en_GB). So if I call `DateFormat.getDateInstance(int fomat,Locale l)` I get always the English one! It works if I use language only Locales (e.g. En, de,...)

I have reviewed the [Oracle Doc of DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html), but also with their examples the Error occurs.

Here is an example Program:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateFormatTest {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Locale[] locales={new Locale("de_AT"),new Locale("de_DE"), new Locale("de"), new Locale("en_US"), new Locale("en"), new Locale("fr_FR"), new Locale("fr_CA"), new Locale("fr")};
    Date today= new Date();
    for(Locale l: locales){
        System.out.println(l.toString()+"\t"+
              DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT,l).format(today)+"\t"+
              DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL,l).format(today));
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
huwa@hubefl-ws:~/tmp$ javac DateFormatTest.java 
huwa@hubefl-ws:~/tmp$ java DateFormatTest 
de_at   Nov 8, 2011 Tuesday, November 8, 2011
de_de   Nov 8, 2011 Tuesday, November 8, 2011
de      08.11.2011  Dienstag, 8. November 2011
en_us   Nov 8, 2011 Tuesday, November 8, 2011
en      Nov 8, 2011 Tuesday, November 8, 2011
fr_fr   Nov 8, 2011 Tuesday, November 8, 2011
fr_ca   Nov 8, 2011 Tuesday, November 8, 2011
fr      8 nov. 2011 mardi 8 novembre 2011
```

Has anybody the same problem? Is there a solution?

Comment: for your information, I have tried it on linux (ubuntu 10.04) useing java:


java version "1.6.0_27"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), the constructors are

```
Locale(String language)
Locale(String language, String country)
Locale(String language, String country, String variant)
```

so when you are creating `new Locale("de_AT")`, it tries to use language "de_AT" which does not exist, so it falls back to the default (English).

Try

```
Locale[] locales={new Locale("de", "AT"), new Locale("de", "DE"), ...};
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you're constructing the `Locale` objects. Pass the country and language as separate arguments, e.g.

```
Locale[] locales = { new Locale("de", "AT"), new Locale("de", "DE"), 
    new Locale("de"), new Locale("en", "US"), new Locale("en"), 
    new Locale("fr", "FR"), new Locale("fr", "CA"), new Locale("fr")};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL,Locale.GERMANY).format(today));
```